# event.accuracy of SensorEvent is giving garbage values

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am trying to log the accuracy of each sensorEvent that I receive. I am using below code to log it inside the method '`onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)`'

```
Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: " + event.accuracy);
```

But unfortunately I am getting the garbage values( some positive numbers and some negative numbers).

As per the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH), I should be getting values in range [-1,3].

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1453#makechanges) and fixed in later versions. I observed the issue with the 4.2 and 4.4.4 versions of android. I tried on AOSP 5.0 , it was not reproducible.